# mockserver-client-1.0.10.pre requires rubygems version ~> 2.3, which is incompatible with the current version, 3.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
ruby version:  '2.5.7'
rails versionL '5.2.0'
gem 'mockserver-client', git: 'https://github.com/quintype/mockserver-client-ruby.git', branch: 'rails-5'
```

While doing bundle I am getting below error

> mockserver-client-1.0.10.pre requires rubygems version ~> 2.3, which
>   is incompatible with the current version, 3.1.2

My bundler version in Gemfile.lock is `bundler (>= 1.3.0)`.

Bundler version which I am using is `Bundler version 1.17.3`.

How can I solve this error?

UPDATE

I already done this

```
gem install "rubygems-update:3.1.2"
Successfully installed rubygems-update-3.1.2
Parsing documentation for rubygems-update-3.1.2
Done installing documentation for rubygems-update after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
➜  subtype git:(2046) ✗ update_rubygems
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: bundler
  Version: 2.1.2
  File: bundler-2.1.2.gem
Bundler 2.1.2 installed
RubyGems 3.1.2 installed
Regenerating binstubs
Parsing documentation for rubygems-3.1.2
Installing ri documentation for rubygems-3.1.2



------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RubyGems installed the following executables:
    /Users/vishal.sadriya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/bin/gem
    /Users/vishal.sadriya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/bin/bundle

Ruby Interactive (ri) documentation was installed. ri is kind of like man
pages for Ruby libraries. You may access it like this:
  ri Classname
  ri Classname.class_method
  ri Classname#instance_method
If you do not wish to install this documentation in the future, use the
--no-document flag, or set it as the default in your ~/.gemrc file. See
'gem help env' for details.
```

UPDATE

Further investigation i find out it's issue of `gem hashie`

```
rails s
Could not find hashie-3.6.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
---
gem install hashie-3.6.0
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'hashie-3.6.0' (>= 0) in any repository
```

Answer (score -1):

After 3 hours googling I figure our issue was related to gem dependency for `gem 'mockserver-client'`.
`bundle check` is command to check whether it fulfills all your gem dependency or not.

```
bundle check
The following gems are missing
 * hashie (3.6.0)
 * logging_factory (0.0.1)
```

Therefore, I resolved the gem dependency issue with install this dependent gem with exact same version in my system.

```
gem install hashie -v 3.6.0
gem install logging_factory -v 0.0.1
```

And boooommm, I am able to do `bundle install` without any error.
`bundle check` is the command which saved my day. :)